# how to increment twice without an error of list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

i need to iterate over my list which is words and increment twice in loop.By first increment i am saving words in l and by 2nd increment i am saving tags in m which are present at i+1. and i need to iterate the loop using single variable that is i here. but it is giving me an error: list index out of range.

```
   i=4      
    while i<len(words): # this loop store words of a file in an array
          l=lemmatizer.lemmatize(words[i]) #array of words is lematized here
          print(l)
          i +=1
          m=words[i]
          print(m)
          if result!=0:
             #do something
           else:
              #do something  
          i+=1
```

Comment: 1: a for loop is nicer to use here. 2: you dont need to increment twice, just use i and i+1 as indices. 3: the loop condition should be i< len(words)-1. EDIT: I stated it wrong, of course you must skip two indices in the loop ( i += 2 )

Comment: when i use words[i+1] it gives me an error of list index out of range.

Comment: See the solutions below. I just noted that you start from i=4, is that correct? Remember that arrays start from i=0, so the first word is at 0 and the first tag is at 1, if I understand your data correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not tested, but here goes:

```
while i<len(words)-1: # this loop store words of a file in an array
      l=lemmatizer.lemmatize(words[i]) #array of words is lematized here
      print(l)

      m=words[i+1]
      print(m)
      if result!=0:
         #do something
       else:
          #do something  
      i+=2
```

-- I think a for loop would be better here, but
while works too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop to go through a list in python is generally not the best way to do it. In your case where you want to take out 2 elements at a time, I would try to do something like `zip(words[::2], words[1::2])` to get an iterator of word pairs. You could use this in your code like:

```
for l, m in zip(words[::2], words[1::2]):
    # do something with l and m
```

Note that when words has an uneven length this will not use the last element, if you rather have a default value for this last element you could use `itertools.zip_longest` like `zip_longest(words[::2], words[1::2], fillvalue='defaultvalue')`.

Comment: nice solution, but probably not easy to understand for a beginner